# How can I stick a <div> to another <div> as it resizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to keep the orange `<div>` "stuck" to the bottom of the google logo as it resizes. Not sure what I need to do to make that happen. The reason for this is that with my actual code, I'll need the call button to stay with the image I have that resizes.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7p6sm2z/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="offer-intro">
    <img class="product-u-shape" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/d/d2/Google_icon_2015.png/revision/latest?cb=20150902024016">
    <div class="offer-intro-image">
        <img src="http://coneyislandpark.com/imgUploader/logos/Pepsi_logo_2008.png" width="220px">
    </div>
<div id="offer-intro-holder">
    <h4>Get up to</h4>
    <h4><strong>$$$$</strong> in <strong>FREE</strong></h4>
    <h4><strong>Equipment</strong><span class="ast">*</span></h4></div>
    <div class="hero-filler"></div>
</div>
<div class="call-now"><span class="call-now-cta">Call now for a free quote</span>
    <br>
    <a class="phone-number" href="tel:888-888-8888">CALL <strong>888.888.8888</strong></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#offer-intro,
#offer-intro-holder {
  max-width: 590px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}

#offer-intro {
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}

#offer-intro img.product-u-shape {
  max-width: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#offer-intro img {
  float: none;
}

#offer-intro #offer-intro-holder h4 {
  color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 45px;
}

.call-now {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.call-now .phone-number {
  background-color: #ff8200;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 690px;
  width: 100%;
}

.offer-intro-image {
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.offer-intro-image img {
  float: none;
  max-width: 226px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 690px) {
  .offer-intro-image {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .call-now {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .call-now .phone-number {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method involves placing both divs inside one parent container.

Assign `position: relative` to the container, then use `position: absolute` on one or both child divs to position them however you want within the parent.

Here's an example using your code (simplified):

**HTML**

```
<div id="offer-intro">
    <img class="product-u-shape" src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/...">
    <div class="call-now"><span class="call-now-cta">Call now for a free quote</span>
        <br>
        <a class="phone-number" href="tel:888-888-8888">CALL <strong>888...</strong></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#offer-intro {
    position: relative;
}

.product-u-shape {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.call-now {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/f7p6sm2z/6/)

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot and let you know if I have any follow up questions.  I viewed the jsfiddle and see what you did, so I'll try it out.  Thank you, will advise if it worked.

Comment: It didn't really work with the tweaks.  I think you're pointing me in the right direction, so I appreciate the help.  I just have to scratch what I have and recode it.

Comment: Well, as you can see, it works in the simplified version. Once you make the parent a positioned element, it becomes the containing block for its absolutely positioned children. The concept and code is sound. You may just have to remove code that disrupts or conflicts with this set-up.

Comment: Yeah I just realized it's not working because ultimately, the representation of the Google logo needs to hover over other div's.  That's the problem I'm having, keeping the items underneath the same, but shrinking the logo and the call now button with it, all hovering over the items behind them.

Comment: Well, whatever hovering you're doing with the logo, consider doing it instead with a div that contains both the logo and the call now button.

Answer (score 1):

Came up with this, dont know if it's what you're looking for:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 325px;
}

.logo {
  padding: 5px;
}

.description {
  background-color: #CF7823;
  text-align: center;
}

.description p {
  padding: 15px;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BvSHAhu.jpg" alt="Logo" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <p>Call Now: <a href="tel:888-888-8888"><b>888.888.8888</b></a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your image seemed pretty big so I downloaded it, re-sized it and then re-uploaded it.

Comment: Let me play around with this as well.  Thank you!